# "like this" vs. "this way"

Tags: phrase-meaning

If I were to spell something out for someone, say a student, I would say:

> Think about it this way, ...

1. Is this correct? If so,
2. Can *this way* be replaced with *like this*? If yes,
3. Are they interchangeable for this very context?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, and *this way* can be replaced with *like this*, however,

They are not interchangeable in every context.

> You have to go this way...

Has a different meaning to

> You have to go like this...

The first means that you have to go in a direction, the second one is, I'm fairly sure, actually incorrect, but I have seen people use when showing someone how to do something.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, those are interchangeable. Both sound like fine English.

Comment: They are not always interchangeable.